# How to know how many applications are running in the background in android?

Tags: android, background-service

I can run an application in background but I want to know how many applications are running in the background. Like in some mobile while pressing the center button a list of currently running applications are displayed.

Is this is possible in android? If possible then give some code snippets and steps to achieve this.

Answer (score 5):

The [*Dev Tools* application](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/development.git;a=blob_plain;f=apps/Development/src/com/android/development/RunningProcesses.java;hb=HEAD) (installed in emulators) shows a list of running processes by obtaining an instance of [`ActivityManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html):

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> l = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

Comment: And how to find Linux kernel related process? getRunningProcesses() only get those Apps running on android framework.

Comment: you can run `ps`, just like on any other linux system